# Calculating time difference in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table `table_a`:

```
event_id        event_start                 process_id          process_start                name            country
A1              2020-07-01 21:19:01         B1                  2020-07-01 21:20:05          google          US
A1              2020-07-01 21:19:01         B2                  2020-07-01 21:21:01          google          US
A1              2020-07-01 21:19:01         B3                  2020-07-01 21:23:04          google          US
A4              2020-07-01 14:59:12         C1                  2020-07-01 15:01:14          bing            UK
A5              2020-07-01 12:39:14         D1                  2020-07-01 12:49:13          bing            CA
A6              2020-07-01 11:49:46         E1                  2020-07-01 11:52:59          facebook        US
```

In this table I have `event_id` which can be the same, if `event_id` is the same, then `event_start` will be the same too. `process_id` is unique, process_start can have duplicate. I am trying to calculate the minute difference between `event_start` and `process_start` for each `event_id`, the problem is that `event_start` has the same time but the `process_start` can have different timestamps. I would like to take 2 times from the `process_start` if they have more than one. First would be the earliest (min) `process_start` and the latest (max) `process_start` so that my desired output would look like so:

```
event_id        event_start                 process_id          process_start                name            country        earliest_diff_minute                                latest_diff_minute
A1              2020-07-01 21:19:01         B1                  2020-07-01 21:20:05          google          US             1 (2020-07-01 21:20:05 - 2020-07-01 21:19:01)       3 (2020-07-01 21:23:05 - 2020-07-01 21:19:04)
A1              2020-07-01 21:19:01         B3                  2020-07-01 21:23:04          google          US             1 (2020-07-01 21:20:05 - 2020-07-01 21:19:01)       3 (2020-07-01 21:23:05 - 2020-07-01 21:19:04)
A4              2020-07-01 14:59:12         C1                  2020-07-01 15:01:14          bing            UK             2 ( 2020-07-01 15:01:14 - 2020-07-01 14:59:12)      2 ( 2020-07-01 15:01:14 - 2020-07-01 14:59:12) 
A5              2020-07-01 12:39:14         D1                  2020-07-01 12:49:13          bing            CA             10                                                  10
A6              2020-07-01 11:49:46         E1                  2020-07-01 11:52:59          facebook        US             3                                                   3
```

So if the `process_id` is unique, the min and max time difference will be the same. If more than 1, both max and min values are recorded while everything in between is discarded.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You seem to care about the `name` and/or `country` columns, but the explanation doesn't clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that duplicates is by `name` and `country`.  You can just use window functions, particularly `min()` and `max()` to get the earliest and latest process dates for each grouping:

```
select a.*,
       datediff('m', event_start, max(process_start) over (partition by event_id, name, country)),
       datediff('m', event_start, min(process_start) over (partition by event_id, name, country))
from table_a a
```

Comment: But you miss to delete the rows with middle value like B2 in the example

Comment: @Hyruma92 . . . As I mention in the comment, the question is unclear.  The filtering is another aspect of why it is unclear.  The text only describes adding a new column.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are various ways to achieve your goal, this is the first that I thought

```
SELECT event_id,
       event_start,
       process_id,
       process_start,
       name,
       country,
       datediff('m', event_start, first_process_start) as earliest_diff_minute,
       datediff('m', last_process_start, event_start) as latest_diff_minute
FROM (
SELECT event_id,
       event_start,
       process_id,
       process_start,
       name,
       country
       first_value(process_start) 
         over (partition by event_id 
               order by process_start 
               rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as first_process_start,
       last_value(process_start) 
         over (partition by event_id 
               order by process_start 
               rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_process_start
FROM my_schema.my_table) as a
WHERE process_start = first_process_start
OR process_start = last_process_start
```

Basically in the sub query for each row you retrieve the first and last process_start. Then you retrieve only the rows that have the process_start equal to one of each and after you can calculate the date difference.

Comment: Thanks, however in the `latest_diff_minute` I need to check event start - > last_process_start, because, in your code above I get negative values, other than that it works, thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, so should be datediff('m', max(last_process_start, event_start), min(last_process_start, event_start)) as latest_diff_minute ... right?

Comment: I don't think so, I just swapped places `date_diff('second', event_start, last_process_start) as latest_diff_second`. But I assume I would get rows where I have both first and last processes times, but now if there is an entry in the `latest_diff_minute` the `earliest_diff_minute` is always `0`, any idea why that would be the case?

Comment: Basically now if there is more than more process, I only see the `latest_diff_minute` and not both. It has to do with the last `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, correct if I'm wrong. In the earliest_diff_minute and latest_diff_minute you want always a positive value that is the result of last/first - event_start or event_start - last/first depends on the value right?

Comment: I would like to see earliest_diff_minute as a result of process_start - evet_start, if there are more process_starts which event_id is the same I want to see the min_time_diff and he max_time_diff, so for example looking ant my first 3 lines I would like to see the result of process B1 time minus the event_time of A1, and since there are 3 A1 events, the last of them would be B3 time minus the same A1 time. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: And I now understood that since you use first and last values, when the data is not sorted that produces incorrect values.

Comment: In the window function there is the order by clause that sort the data, so it shouldn't be an issue. Furthermore, for the result that you said, the query works, you can always call the abs function. I put your data into my table and works fine